# Restrict an iTunes smart playlist to contain only entire albums

Tags: itunes, ipod, playlists, smart-playlist

I'm trying to create an "albums not played for the last 3 months" playlist, that I could sync onto my iPod.

Is it normal that autofill always chooses the same songs out of my library to fill the iPod with? No matter what I do to those tracks (listen to them on the iPod, try do delete them in "manual" mode), they always come back when I sync with autofill.

I do have quite a substantial amount of other tracks that I like as well, but it feels like autofill picked once and for all the tracks it likes most.

I have read the [*Managing Your iPod With Smartlists* document (PDF)](http://forums.ilounge.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=6965&d=1181024691) ([non-PDF link](http://docs.google.com/gview?a=v&q=cache:YJc0ok5W-2AJ:forums.ilounge.com/attachment.php%3Fattachmentid%3D6965%26d%3D1181024691+%22Managing+Your+iPod+With+Smartlists%22&hl=en&gl=us&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESjrxmWCvWH2ZH94EDbsqqxuGpjrcqVM8HUaqWxheS4gklKOVTH2zHUR9w-f6FGF6AnFpJf1GF88w7S_vS9X7lH5Q39ySFNm1g8QNSic6_K7tufyPOfpz8TjwyMyG7Mi74HRNG49&sig=AFQjCNH2e5MM_gMxCRE3a4EVJ2tn5Ww_mg)) but nothing has come of it.

I own a 2G iPod nano (first generation) that I'm using together with iTunes 9.0.1 on my Mac.

Answer (score 2):

I sympathize completely. This is one of my biggest complaints with iTunes - that it doesn't inherently make any distinction between complete albums and "singles" - random tracks that aren't with a complete album.

What I've ended up doing is systematically clearing the album tag from all singles. You can then make a smart playlist that omits tracks with no album. If it bothers you to mess with the metadata that way, you can find a different attribute to change, as long as you're consistent and it's something smart playlists can filter for.

Answer (score 1):

I did not find a way to to this using smart playlists, but in the end i still acheived my goal (i.e. get random albums onto my ipod) thanks to an application called [NanoFibre](http://steelskies.com/article/49/nanofibre-for-sensible-generation-of-ipod-playlists).

Enjoy...